# Geo-location clustering

Tags: geolocation, location, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I have a customer location streaming data, which i need to analyze and check out for each event if the location is his usual visited location or not and generate an alert in real time if its not his usually visited location.
I was looking at various clustering algorithms but couldn't find a good one which do it in 'real time'.

Kmeans is too rigid with number of centriods.. DBSCAN is heavy weight and not sure if its fast enough to respond in real time...

Can you suggest one, which suits the real time stream processing?

Comment: A good DBSCAN implementation will scale well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe DBSCAN is suitable enough. Its worst-case-scenario complexity is O(n2) which is decent enough compared to other traditional algorithms such as hierarchical. In comparison to kmeans, I believe that kmeans is applicable if you use a ST_Centroid function from a spatial database such as SpatiaLIte or PostGIS ( take for granted that you use geographic data).
Between kmeans and DBSCAN, I choose DBSCAN because I think the answer to your problem is a density-based approach regarding real-time data.